# How to update query with new parameter excluding it from GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE spend_google (
    campaign_id,
    campaign_name,
    spend_eur,
    date
);

CREATE TABLE spend_google_data (
    campaign_id,
    campaign_name,
    spend_eur,
    date,
    ad_group,
    ad_group_id,
    ad_asset,

);
```

**query**

```
WITH campaign_spends AS (

    SELECT
        campaign_id,
        SUM(spend_eur) AS campaign_spend
    FROM
         spend_google
    WHERE
        date BETWEEN '2022-05-19' AND '2022-05-31'
    GROUP BY
        campaign_id
),
creatives_spends AS (

    SELECT
        campaign_id,
        campaign_name,
        CASE
            WHEN ad_group LIKE 'Ad_group_%' THEN
                REGEXP_SUBSTR( ad_asset, '([a-z]{2,3}\_[a-z]+\\d{3,5})|([a-z]{2,3}\_[a-z]+\\d{3,5}[v]\\d{1,3})')
            ELSE ad_group
        END AS creative,
        SUM(spend_eur) AS creative_spend,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY campaign_id ORDER BY creative_spend DESC) AS top_position
   FROM
        spend_google_data
   WHERE
        date BETWEEN '2022-05-19' AND '2022-05-31'
        AND
        creative != ''
   GROUP BY
        campaign_id,
        campaign_name,
        creative
   ORDER BY
        creative_spend DESC
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    creatives_spends
    INNER JOIN campaign_spends USING ( campaign_id )

WHERE
    top_position > 5
    AND
    creative_spend < campaign_spend / 100 * 4
    AND
    campaign_name IN 'some campaign names'

ORDER BY
    campaign_id,
    top_position;
```

query result:

| `campaign_id` | `campaign_name` | `creative` | `creative_spend` | `top_position` | `campaign_spend` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17225980452 | `HS_GP_UAC_Value_22.05.11` | `hs_video1143v1` | `389.162404` | `6` | `23403.87` |
| 17225980452 | `HS_GP_UAC_Value_22.05.11` | `hs_video3090v6` | `353.362789` | `7` | `23403.87` |
| 17225980452 | `HS_GP_UAC_Value_22.05.11` | `hs_video3089v1` | `341.295940` | `8` | `23403.87` |

I also need to add the ad_group column from the spend_google_data table to the result. But just add it to SELECT

```
creatives_spends AS (
    SELECT
        campaign_id,
        campaign_name,
        ad_group      <-- here
```

I can't, because then I need to add `ad_group` to `GROUP BY` and this will change the query result for the table.

So , the question is how can the ad_group column be added to the result without adding it to GROUP BY ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please post a DBFiddle or SQLFiddle with sample data.

Comment: _"How can the `ad_group` column be added to the result without adding it to GROUP BY ?"_ - use another CTE step to `INNER JOIN` the aggregate results back with `spend_google_data` to get `ad_group`.

Comment: Can you add an example of how the result changes by adding that column? I mean, adding a column to a query with aggregate functions WILL change the result if that new column can have more than 1 value per `GROUP BY` combination, that's how they work; but having an idea of what you want to avoid (and why) could help to find a workaround.

Comment: @JoshPart This can be a bit tricky to understand if you don't know the business logic, but in short the same `creative` can be in several `ad_groups` in one `campaign` and adding an `ad_group` in `ORDER BY` changes the calculation of the `creative_spend` parameter

Comment: That's my point: if, say, the `hs_video1143v1` creative is in two different `ad_group`s, adding the `ad_group` column will split the total of `creative_spend` among those two `ad_group`s; if you DON'T want that, then you'll have to have only one of the two `ad_group`s in your resultset, but the final query will depend on how do you need to choose or specify which one you want to show

Answer (score 0):

- Compute *only* the aggregates (the `SUM` (`creative_spend`) and `ROW_NUMBER` (`top_position`)) for each `spend_google_data.campaign_id` in a separate CTE step (`creatives_spends_step_1`).
- Then `INNER JOIN` that (`pt1`) with the original `spend_google_data` to get non-aggregate data like `ad_group` and `creative`.
- Also....

  - Remove "non-key" columns from `GROUP BY` (it's a code-smell and causes unexpected results if you're not careful).
  - `ORDER BY` in a CTE or derived-table is redundant, so I removed it.
- Like so...:

```
WITH campaign_spends AS (
    SELECT
        campaign_id,
        SUM(spend_eur) AS campaign_spend
    FROM
        spend_google
    WHERE
        date BETWEEN '2022-05-19' AND '2022-05-31'
    GROUP BY
        campaign_id
),
creatives_spends_step_1 AS (
   SELECT
        d.campaign_id,
        SUM( d.spend_eur ) AS creative_spend,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY d.campaign_id ORDER BY d.creative_spend DESC ) AS top_position
   FROM
        spend_google_data AS d
   WHERE
        ( d.date BETWEEN '2022-05-19' AND '2022-05-31' )
        AND
        d.ad_group != ''
   GROUP BY
        d.campaign_id
),
creatives_spends_step_2 AS (

    SELECT
        pt1.campaign_id,
        pt1.creative_spend,
        pt1.top_position
        d.campaign_name,
        CASE
            WHEN d.ad_group LIKE 'Ad_group_%' THEN
                REGEXP_SUBSTR( d.ad_asset, '([a-z]{2,3}\_[a-z]+\\d{3,5})|([a-z]{2,3}\_[a-z]+\\d{3,5}[v]\\d{1,3})')
            ELSE
                d.ad_group
        END AS creative
   FROM
        creatives_spends_step_1 AS pt1
        INNER JOIN spend_google_data AS d ON pt1.campaign_id = d.campaign_id
)
SELECT
    pt2.campaign_id,
    pt2.campaign_name,
    pt2.creative
    pt2.creative_spend
    pt2.top_position

    cs.campaign_id,
    cs.campaign_spend
FROM
    creatives_spends_step_2 AS pt2
    INNER JOIN campaign_spends AS cs ON pt2.campaign_id = cs.campaign_id 
WHERE
    pt2.top_position > 5
    AND
    cs.creative_spend < ( cs.campaign_spend / ( 100 * 4 ) )
    AND
    pt2.campaign_name IN ( 'some campaign names' )

ORDER BY
    pt2.campaign_id,
    pt2.top_position;
```

Comment: looks rather complicated to me) I have tried the query, but there is a problem with the string `AND creative != ''` .  creative does not exist in `spend_google_data`

Comment: @Jekson Thank you for catching that. I've corrected the query.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `ad_asset` field in the table structure which is in my query. So the condition you added `d.ad_group != ''` is not quite right, ad_group cannot be empty.

Comment: `AND creative != '' `are used to filter out values that do not fit the regular expression and will be detected as empty strings.